# CheckableLinearLayout background does change with background selector

Tags: android, listview, selector, android-linearlayout

iv been struggling with this problem for at least one day by now, searching over the internet but no solution worked for me, ive been trying to understand why it happens, and how to fix it the right way.

The problem:
I was unable to change the row background color/drawable when it is "checked", I know when it is checked because my root element implements **Checked** interface.

I dont know the difference between set the property **android:listSelector** of the ListView and the **android:background** property of my row root element (CheckableLinearLayout).

What property will Android use the selector and apply my background? because none of them is working until now, it is always transparent.

In some cases, when i tap the list item, the item goes red and then back to transparent, also the method *onCreateDrawableState* never gets really called, I think it might be related.

My Scenario:

**API 10 (2.3.3)**

One Activity with a ListView using a custom adapter that extends ArrayAdapter.
My ListView row resource root element:

```
    <com.company.views.CheckableLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
...
```

*CheckableLinearLayout*:

```
public class CheckableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {
private static final int[] STATE_CHECKED = {android.R.attr.state_checked};

        @Override
        protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace)
        {
...
            int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);

            if (isChecked())
                mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_CHECKED);

            return drawableState;
        }
...
    }
```

My selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/solid_blue" />
    </shape>
</item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/solid_red" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I even tried to use a empty selector where it sets the background to red, but still, my row doenst goes red.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, the code above is right, I discover that in a previous attempt in another place of my code I was setting my list item background to transparent.

After removing that code, I set my listview listSelector to a transparent selector (to remove the orange selection background).

And then set the CheckableLinearLayout background to my selector above.

After that my onCreateDrawableState gets normally called and the background changes as specified in the selector.

That's it!